# Web page not Avaible Go another class or show an image

Tags: android, networking, webview, connect

1-)i have a webview project.sometimes im forgot my internet connect.and its showing webpage not available.when if this be i want to go another class or show error.xml its so bad displaying.
thanks all.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webplayer);
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);   
        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);   
        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String url = i.getStringExtra("url");  // retrieve the value you passed
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {    
            webView.loadUrl(url);  // use that value
        }        
    }  

public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }       
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }       
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }        
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }

            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View mVideoProgressView;


        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
           onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }               
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {   
            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(webplayer.this);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();   
            mCustomView = null;
        }
    } 
     @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
        customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

        mCustomView = null;

    }
}

class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Comment: anybody don't know answer ?

Comment: help ! ?? i need an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simply very easy

you can check internet conncection before requesting url

```
 final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) YourClass.this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {

 webView.loadUrl(url);  

}else{
setContentView(R.layout.your);
}
```

//required permissions

add these permissions to your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

for more help contect me at rajeshsaini890 at gmail

Comment: hey bro can u help me about this @raj http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592219/get-data-on-html-div-android

Comment: need help bro :) @raj
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885437/webview-load-data-before-onclick