# Webview load data before onClick

Tags: android, webview, background

my project working like

1. Showing activity main and im older than 13 years ago button. If u click button opening website some horror films.
2. Opening webview and loading website.

now my fail here.the user clicked button and waiting 5-6 second ? i want to make this like

1. Showing activity_main and click button (and loading website background)
2. Showing webview not waiting page was loaded !

**Activity_main (first)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);                
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent it=new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, web.class)) ;   
         startActivity(it);
    }
    });
}
```

**web.class**

```
public class web extends Activity {     
    private WebView webView;
       private View mCustomView ;    
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);         
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);    
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);       
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);      
        webView.loadUrl("http:/zzzzzz..x.x.x.x..x.x");

        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) web.this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {

            return;

    }else{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }    
        }  
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } 
    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }    
}
}
```

activity main (manitibo)

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Onaylıyorum" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Uyarı !"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Onaylıyorum butonuna bastığınızda 18 yaş ve üzeri olduğunuzu kabul etmiş sayılırsınız !"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Destek: xxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/asdaa" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: i want to get data for webview load page.but i dont want starting loading when i click button and run class.webview.i want start when   app started.

Comment: When it first opened the application welcome screen appears. When you press a button here and there trying WebView class. As soon as you try WebView page is loading. but when I opened the first page buttons in page load I want WebView. When the button is pressed to open the page directly preloaded want. For a lot of users are waiting for the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // Layout elements
    private Button btn_aboveage = null;
    private WebView webView = null;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Attach layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve layout elements
        btn_aboveage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_aboveage);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        // Load page
        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);    
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);       
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);      
        webView.loadUrl("http:/zzzzzz..x.x.x.x..x.x");

        // Check Internet connectivity
        if (!hasInternet())
        {
            // TODO : Display alert dialog !
        }

        // Attach listener
        btn_aboveage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_aboveage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // TODO : Hide layout elements you don't want to be displayed while in webview mode.
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean hasInternet()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        return (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            if (webView != null && webView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && webView.canGoBack())
            {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private static class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the layout I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_aboveage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignVertical="true"
        android:text="I'm above 13" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it was working but im abowe 13 years old ann homepage not cleaned They got on top of how can i hide other icon and texts  ?

Comment: and when i click any link on web page coming back button

Comment: I don't understand what you try to explain.

Comment: First screen is normal when I click button only button is hidding other texts and logo not hidding they got on webview I added activity main .xml

Comment: I'm not totally sure of what you ask for, but give a look to the code I've just updated. You should hide the elements you don't want to be displayed.